# sharethis not working properly on sharing link for facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, sharethis

I've used sharthis plugin for sharing news link for my website. There is problem in sharing link for facebook like it's now showing the image, title, description of the news. I've googled this and added the open graph tags (`og:url, og:title, og:description, og:image`) and defined namespace as well but still now working. I've tested facebook debugger tools(`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug`), i didn't get any error message but still it doesn't sharing properly. Is there any problem with my site content, because my news are in unicode and i've used unicode slug in my url as well. Please help me.

Comment: If you are attempting this on a local server, or something behind a login (e.g. HT Authentication), it will not work. Basically the Facebook server needs to access the URL publicly in order to grab the opengraph tags and then it will cache them.

Comment: Yes i know that and i'm not testing it in local server it's in live server and i found other services like google+, linkedin and twitter are working fine, just facebook is not working

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this is not still a problem now, but the [Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) can be very useful when having problems with Open Graph metadata.